# Suggested way to delete things POINTING to PFObject when deleting said PFObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, parse-platform

I was just wondering what the easiest/suggested way is to delete a PFObject and everything related to it. For example, in a photo sharing app, if the uploader wanted to delete a photo he/she posted, how do you also delete all the "likes" and comments associated with that photo?

Right now, I'm using:

```
[PFObject deleteInBackground]
```

but that only deletes the object itself. I understand I can query for activities pointing to the post and deleting those one by one like so:

```
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"activity"];
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
    [query whereKey:@"image" equalTo:PFObject];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        for (int i = 0; i < [objects count]; i++) {
            [[objects objectAtIndex:i] deleteInBackground];
        }
    }];
```

I was just wondering if this was the typical way of doing or if there is an easier way. I'd like to minimize the number of queries in my app so it would be beneficial if there was a way to do it without querying "activities".

Also for future reference, is it typical to delete all things that point to an object or is it better to just filter it out when presenting it?

Comment: To those who've flagged this. I've added more code to demonstrate what I've tried. Please reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually better to filter out "deleted" objects rather than deleting them outright. You could try creating a Cloud Function that flags the parent object, as well as any related objects, as "deleted".